# my batis conditional execution of query WHERE clause based on null variable passed in

Tags: java, sql, spring, mybatis

In my batis, I have a query that will be used to query based on date, else it should just get sysdate between a range. There are 2 potentially executable where clauses, but I would only like to execute one of them.

```
SELECT distinct support_id AS object_id, 2 as app_context_id, 
            0 as domain_cdc_id, 'S' as object_type, 'NEW' as domain_cdc_status, 1 as attribute_group_num, 
            sysdate as created_on FROM fdrdbo.v_facility_support 
            WHERE support_version_valid_from_dt = to_date('${passedInVar}', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

IF ${passedInVar} is null, then I want the following WHERE condition to be used!

```
WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN support_version_valid_from_dt AND support_version_valid_to_dt
```

How can I build it like this?

Answer (score 4):

Use [dynamic SQL](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html#if)

```
SELECT distinct support_id AS object_id, 2 as app_context_id, 
        0 as domain_cdc_id, 'S' as object_type, 'NEW' as domain_cdc_status, 1 as attribute_group_num, 
        sysdate as created_on FROM fdrdbo.v_facility_support 
WHERE
<if test="passedInVar != null">
    support_version_valid_from_dt = to_date('${passedInVar}', 'yyyy/mm/dd') 
</if>
<if test="passedInVar == null">
    SYSDATE BETWEEN support_version_valid_from_dt AND support_version_valid_to_dt
</if>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join the two WHEREs in one like this :

```
WHERE
('${passedInVar}' IS NULL AND SYSDATE BETWEEN support_version_valid_from_dt AND support_version_valid_to_dt)
OR
('${passedInVar}' IS NOT NULL AND support_version_valid_from_dt = to_date('${passedInVar}', 'yyyy/mm/dd'))
```