# SELECT WHERE value may or may not be NULL

Tags: mybatis

MyBatis 3.4.6

I want to find a record based on the value of a String field in a Java object. The Java field and the database can both be null and when they are, I want to select the record. The XML below seems to work:

```
  <select id='selectFoo' parameterType='foo' resultType='int'>
    SELECT id FROM foo WHERE
            (bar = #{bar} OR (bar IS NULL AND #{bar,jdbcType=VARCHAR} IS NULL)
```

I wonder if this is the correct way to handle it? (Just using 'bar = #{bar}' does not handle the case of both being null, I want the SELECT to return a record and it doesn't).

From my (limited) knowledge of JDBC outside of MyBatis, the same sort of thing is necessary there, so I'm doubtful that there is a better way, but I wanted to check as I don't understand this stuff very well and it seems clunky.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [my batis conditional execution of query WHERE clause based on null variable passed in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713758/my-batis-conditional-execution-of-query-where-clause-based-on-null-variable-pass)

Answer (score 0):

That is not wrong, but with MyBatis, we typically write ...

```xml
WHERE
<if test="bar != null">bar = #{bar}</if>
<if test="bar == null">bar IS NULL</if>
```

or

```xml
WHERE
<choose>
  <when test="bar != null">bar = #{bar}</when>
  <otherwise>bar IS NULL</otherwise>
</choose>
```

Please see the [doc](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html) for more practical examples.